# ASP.NET Core 3.0 - Model Binding not inferred?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.0

According to the documentation, complex types should automatically be handled as "FromBody" without the need to decorate the parameter with an attribute. For whatever reason it isn't working for me. What am I missing? Thanks.

ASP.NET Core 3, Content Type of the Header is "application/json".

[image]

Comment: You need `[FromBody]` specifically for json. If you pass data as `key=value&..` it's not needed

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens? I have the same issue and I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference)

> The [ApiController] attribute applies inference rules for the default data sources of action parameters. These rules save you from having to identify binding sources manually by applying attributes to the action parameters.

The complex types could automatically be handled as "FromBody" when you use the `[ApiController]` attribute on the controller .